# git bitbucket ssh windows

Tags: windows, git, bash, bitbucket

I have switched to windows and I've been installing and setting up my environment, I have solved most of my initial frustrations, but when going through this guide:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git

and copying the script, it fails to achieve the desired result. I do not remember much bash, and I do not know the limitations of gitbash on windows... Please advise. I also do not get the desired result from the git-add -l

Is the tutorial outdated?

Comment: Which script? The one in step 5? What result **does** it achieve? Did you read the note about copying and pasting from Chrome and Opera? What result **do** you get from `git add`? Where do you see `git add -l`? `-l` isn't a flag to `git add` that I'm aware of.

Comment: yes, step 5.  it has no effect when launching the gitbash prompt. And yes, I tried using other browsers and even typed it up myself, none of it worked. and sorry i meant ssh-add -l have a bit of a headache after a couple of hours with this mess.

Comment: What do you mean it has no effect? You don't see those messages echoed to the screen? What file did you edit exactly? What does `command -V start_agent` output in the git bash shell? What does `ssh-add -l` output?

Comment: It doesnt change at all. I used my bashrc, It is a linux bashrc I had quickly available, so I used it. I deleted it all and created a new one and still nothing! when activating my bashrc it noticeably changes things, but still no prompt to put in details and no echo.

Comment: Which file **exactly**? What does `file ~/.bashrc; wc -l ~/.bashrc` say at the git bash prompt? What about my other questions?

Comment: sorry about that, must have overlooked. It says start_agent is a function and displays it!

Comment: not sure about the file ~/.bashrc; wc -l ~/.bashrc  ? you want me to enter it into the prompt? not valid commands

Comment: What happens when you run `start_agent`? Do you have the line running it in the bashrc file? Yes, at the git bash prompt. Hm...  it may not have `file` but it does have `wc`. But you can ignore those for now since we know the function is in there.

Comment: the following section is in the script from the guide:

Comment: if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
     . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
     ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
        start_agent;
    }
else
    start_agent;
fi

Comment: just loaded it up for the first time since yesterday and it now has changed, however, it still does not query me for authorization as the guide suggests. It starts as usual and proceeds to echo starting new ssh agent, succeeded.  executing ssh-add -l return no identities

Comment: nope, now its stopped again...

Comment: Have you created your ssh key? Is it named `.ssh/id_rsa`?

Comment: I have two created, one which was used for linux and the other I use for windows. It is in my config file and it works fine. At first I had problems but I sorted them out, now I can use the repository, though it requires me to type in a password for everything. The script was supposedly meant to sort that. It is not called id_rsa though, it is titled winGit

Comment: `ssh-add` when called without an argument only tries the default file names. So either rename your file or add the path to your key to the `ssh-add` call in the snippet.

Comment: Ah!  thanks. I added the path to the ssh-add section of the script, now when I start the shell it starts as before, but when calling ssh-add -l it shows some hex values , the path and ends with (RSA) 
still don't get prompted for my pass though.

Comment: Does your key have a passphrase?

Comment: Then `ssh-add` should be asking you for it when it tries to add the key. If `ssh-add` can add the key you listed without asking you for a passphrase then that key doesn't have a passphrase. (Just to be clear a passphrase on the key is different then a password on the account on the remote system.) What happens if you run `ssh-add <key-with-a-passphrase>`?

Comment: It definitely has a passphrase, I just made a new pair just to be sure, still doesn't happen, and the echos aren't being displayed either

Comment: When I ssh-add <path to winGit> it prompts for pass

Comment: when I call start_agent it echos and prompts now, but for some reason its not called when i start bash

Comment: I just deleted a space from if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then   making it if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}"]; then  

and now when starting bash it  says sh.exe": [: missing `]' 
then proceeds to echo and prompt for pass...

Comment: You need spaces before and after both `[` and `]` in that line. They aren't syntax.

Comment: I know, but when I change that it shows an error, then actually works.

Comment: The error is just falling into the `else` block of the if statement. So if that's the block that "works" you need to find out why the other block is running when it shouldn't be.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.
I just started my shell in the Desktop, and it worked, but when I closed it and tried it against in another directory, it failed?

Comment: Did you use a relative path to the key file? Relative to the desktop? Use a full path instead. (Assuming that's the problem you are discussing.)

Comment: I used ~/.ssh/winGit

Comment: That's a full path. That should work no matter where you are then. Other bits of the code might have problems I suppose but that would be more surprising. Putting `set -x` in the init script above the code in question might tell you something useful about what is going on (and `set +x` after to turn it back off).

Comment: I am now 90% confident I've got it all working! Thanks for your help : )